# Получить запрос с веб-сокета

Tags: c#, json, websocket

Как написать запрос в веб-сокет C# с помощью JSON? Использую .NET Framework 4.7.2, WPF

```cs
using WebSocketSharp;

private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {
        WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.10.250:8002");
        ws.Connect();
        qwe.Text = ws.Send(Json.Decode("'cmd':'get_device_appdata_resp'"));
    }
    catch { qwe.Text = "увы"; }
}
```

есть API пример работы запроса

> Example request message:

```json
{
    "cmd" : "get_device_appdata_req"
}
```

> Example response message:

```json
{
    "cmd": "get_device_appdata_resp",
    "status": true,
    "devices_list":
    [
        {
            "devEui": "3933363845366606",
            "appEui": "0000000000000001",
            "devName": "Окно",
            "adress1": "Kurgan",
            "devType": "Test",
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

К веб-сокету подключаюсь, но не могу сделать json-запрос чтобы получить как пример выше

Comment: Что такое `Json.Decode`? какой тип приложения, версия .NET и что такое `ws`, то есть какую именно библиотеку для работы с вебсокетами вы используете? Дополните вопрос, его можно редактировать.

Comment: если `ws.Send` принимает `string` на вход, то можно так `ws.Send("{\"cmd\":\"get_device_appdata_req\"}")` или так `ws.Send(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { cmd = "get_device_appdata_req" }))`

Comment: если у вас старый .NET Framework, в котором нет `System.Text.Json`, то можете установить NuGet пакет для работы с JSON - `Newtonsoft.Json`, тогда в примере выше замените `JsonSerializer.Serialize` на `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: что в одном что в другом случае пишет "не удается неявно преобразовать тип void в string"

Comment: `qwe.Text = ` уберите. `Send` отправляет данные. Получать их следует другим образом. Посмотрите примеры, почитайте [документацию](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client).

Comment: нашел вот такое решение на питоне await ws.send('{"cmd":"get_device_appdata_req"}')
        async for mess in ws:
            msg = jsn.loads(mess)
            if msg["cmd"] == "get_device_appdata_resp":
                break
        print(msg)

Comment: Я же вам только что выше ссылку на документацию скинул, где пример на C#. o_O Или вы не переходите по незнакомым ссылкам?

Comment: Перехожу, но эта вариация тоже не помогла. Необходимость именно json запрос к websocket как описано выше из API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пример из [документации](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client) немного доработать, получится вот так.

```cs
using WebSocketSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

```cs
private async void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.10.250:8002"))
        {
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                qwe.Text = e.Data;
                cts?.Cancel();
            };

            ws.Connect();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { cmd = "get_device_appdata_req" });
            ws.Send(json);
            qwe.Text = "Ждем ответа...";
            await Task.Delay(5000, cts.Token);
            qwe.Text = "Время вышло, а ответа от сервера нет";
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException) { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        qwe.Text = "увы, " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```